# Excel VBA/Macro removing unwanted commas from .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a macro/piece of code in excel vba to send the current worksheet to a specific email in .txt format but when I receive the email there are several unneeded commas listed in the file I'm just trying to possibly find a piece of code that will remove these extra commas when the file is sent over in the email. I currently have another macro created which opens and reads the file and removes the unwanted commas but i am having to save the email attachment first whereas I'd like to just receive the clean .txt file directly to my email.

The current .txt file I am receiving looks like;

```
S99,2602,7/12/2017,
10405,PUSH NUT PLAIN 1/4,2.000,EACH
WVC424,CORD 2.2MM E/S CHESTNUT,3.800,MTR
,,,
```

whereas I need it to look like;

```
S99,2602,7/12/2017
10405,PUSH NUT PLAIN 1/4,2.000,EACH
WVC424,CORD 2.2MM E/S CHESTNUT,3.800,MTR
```

For It to be read into our system.

```
Sub EmailAsCSV()
'
' EmailAsCSV Macro
'
 Dim csvFiles(1 To 3) As String, i As Integer
    Dim wsName As Variant
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object




    i = 0
    For Each wsName In Array("Sheet1")     'sheet names to be emailed - CHANGE THE SHEET NAMES
        i = i + 1
        csvFiles(i) = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & wsName & ".txt"
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs csvFiles(i), FileFormat:=xlCSV
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Next


    'Email the .csv files

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("E1").Value     'cell containing email address - CHANGE THE SHEET NAME AND CELL
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Order"
        .Body = "This email contains 1 file attachment with an order."
        .Attachments.Add csvFiles(1)

        .Send
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

    'Delete the .csv files

    Kill csvFiles(1)

'
End Sub

Sub test()
    Dim fn As String, txt As String
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("TextFiles,*.txt")
    If fn = "" Then Exit Sub
    txt = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True: .MultiLine = True
        .Pattern = ",+$"
        Open Replace(fn, ".txt", "_Clean.txt") For Output As #1
            Print #1, .Replace(txt, "")
        Close #1
    End With
End Sub
```

The code I have currently got is listed above.

Comment: I'm guessing that the unwanted commas are on the right of each line. These represent empty columns that Excel *thinks* are being used and must be included in the export. Isolate the area that you want to export or write a loop that generates the CSV independently.

Answer (score 0):

Try saving it in text format instead?

`FileFormat:=xlText`

Comment: This removed all commas rather than only the unneeded ones

Comment: The reason you are getting those extra commas is most likely because there are cells at the end of your data that have spaces in them. Before saving the file you will want to process the data and strip out the cells that have the spaces in them.

Comment: You may also want to look into how to save just a certain range of cells to the CSV file, but either way, you are going to have to have some code that can detect where the end of the data is.

Comment: The extra commas aren't caused by cells with spaces in them.  Excel tries to guess how many columns are being written out, and then inserts the necessary commas to pad the output to that number of columns.  So the fact that there is something in cell `D2` makes Excel decide to also write out cell `D1` even though it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy just the used range (not tested):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).UsedRange.CurrentRegion.Copy
With Workbooks.Add
    .Sheets(1).Paste
    .SaveAs csvFiles(i), FileFormat:=xlCSV
    .Close False
End With
```

or paste the values without formatting (also not tested):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).UsedRange.Copy
With Workbooks.Add
    ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    .SaveAs csvFiles(i), FileFormat:=xlCSV
    .Close False
End With
```

Comment: I tested both these and neither method works, first piece of code just gives same output & second piece removes every comma.